# PowerShell - creating a module from C#

Tags: c#, powershell, module

Okay, I have been fumbling with this project for quite a while.  I can't take credit for any of the code.  What I would like to do is be able to efficiently parse a PDF file and search for keyword(s) using PowerShell.  I found beefycode's Convertfrom-PDF cmdlet: http://www.beefycode.com/post/ConvertFrom-PDF-Cmdlet.aspx
That seems like what I need, of course it also seems to require a PDFParser class from here: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/14170/Extract-Text-from-PDF-in-C-100-NET

I have figured out how to compile the source files from these sites and create .dll files, and how to create a folder in my user-module location to put these .dlls in.

Now, i'm stuck on compiling the cmdlet that contains the Convertfrom-PDF command.  I'm getting this error.
Add-Type : c:\Users\12345\AppData\Local\Temp\u0ofo-9-.0.cs(11) : Warning as Error: Field 'PowerShell.PDF.ConvertFromPDF._PDFFile' is never assigned 
to, and will always have its default value null

Does this make sense to Powershell?

```
[Cmdlet( VerbsData.ConvertFrom, "PDF" )]
public class ConvertFromPDF : Cmdlet
```

Not only that, but i'm baffled out how to work with a source file with a .csproj extension without visual studio.  I ended up just opening up with notepad and saving it with a .cs extension.

Can anyone help shed some light on my problems?  I probably should have started with something smaller, to begin learning how to create modules.

Basically, i've got 2 classes, each needs to be compiled.  Then there's the assemblyinfo.cs file that needs to be compiled.  It's the .csproj source file that seems to wrap these all up into a nice little package...and that is the file I am unable to compile.

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

.CSPROJ files are not really source code files.  They are Visual Studio C# project files that contain settings that determine how the associated .CS (source) files are built.  One of those settings will turn warnings into errors.  Apparently that setting is enabled in your project file. You can open the project file in Visual Studio C# Express (which is free) or you can edit it manually and disable this setting.

Another option is to skip the project file and just manually compile the primary source file (not the assemblyInfo.cs file).  If you have the .NET SDK installed open a command prompt and run:

```
csc /t:library /out:foo.dll file.cs
```

And if you have multiple CS files:

```
csc /t:library /out:foo.dll *.cs
```

That should create a file.dll assembly in the same directory.

Comment: thank you, I have a been able to compile the primary source file using the Powershell ISE, The project file seems to take that, another source file (that contains the cmdlet), and the assemblyinfo file.  When I attempt to compile that .csproj file (that' i've turned into a .cs file), I get multiple "Unexpected character '\'" errors and "A namespace does not directly contain members such as fields or members"

Comment: You can't compile the CSPROJ file using csc.exe.  If you really want to `build` the CSPROJ file, first edit the setting that converts warnings to errors then run `MSBuild.exe foo.csproj`.  BTW do you not want to open/build this in Visual Studio for some reason?

Comment: i've actually downloaded Visual Studio 10 express, and am able to open the project file.  Everything looks fine, but I am still hung up on how to actually implement the cmdlet.  There is a cmdlet.cs file and another .cs file that contains a class required by the cmdlet.cs file; these are all contained in a namespace (which is the name of the .csproj).  I understand that this is an 'inheritance' of sorts, but I am still learning C# and can't get it to work.  I can create a .dll file out of the .cs file the .cmdlet inherits from, but am unable to successfully create a .dll out of the .cmdlet.cs